# A Combinatorics Question Choosing Paths on a Grid

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

This is for a Year 11 HSC Maths Course.

I'm currently stuck at the first part. At each point there should be 2 ways of select where you go (except the bottom and right edges). Since there are $5*7=35$ points on the gird, and there are 11 points on the bottom and right edges, there are $2^{35-11}=2^{24}$ possible routes without restrictions.

But this approach seems to be flawed as it does not match the answers. Could someone suggest a way of thinking about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get from $A$ to $B$ you must take a total of $4$ steps to the right and $6$ steps down, and you can take those $10$ steps in any order. Thus, there is one path for each possible ordering of the $10$ steps. The order is completely determined if you know which $4$ of the $10$ are steps to the right, and they can be any $4$, so there are $\binom{10}4$ possible paths.

If you must pass through $C$, you can combine any path from $A$ to $C$ with any path from $C$ to $B$.

If you cannot move along the top line, your first move must be down, and then you have another problem like the first one.

And if you cannot move along the second row from the top, your first two steps down cannot be split by a step to the right. You can think of this as a combination of several problems like the second one, depending on how far you go along the top line before going down, or you can think of it as a problem just like the first one, but on a slightly smaller grid.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @JieshunWang: You’re very welcome.